# Google Apps Scripts Update Subject and CC with compose at same time

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I would like to open the compose UI and be able to update the draft subject / recipients / and CC all at the same time, not in multiple operations.

The sample code Google gives you doesn't work out of the box, you need to correct the errors. Here is the working code.

```
/**
     * Compose trigger function that fires when the compose UI is
     * requested. Builds and returns a compose UI for inserting images.
     *
     * @param {event} e The compose trigger event object. Not used in
     *         this example.
     * @return {Card[]}
     */
    function startApp(e) {
      return [buildComposeCard()];
    }

    /**
     * Build a card to display interactive buttons to allow the user to
     * update the subject, and To, Cc, Bcc recipients.
     *
     * @return {Card}
     */
    function buildComposeCard() {

      var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
      var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Update email');
      cardSection.addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
              .setText('Update subject')
              .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
                  .setFunctionName('applyUpdateSubjectAction')));
      cardSection.addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
              .setText('Update To recipients')
              .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
                  .setFunctionName('applyUpdateToRecipientsAction')));
      cardSection.addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
              .setText('Update Cc recipients')
              .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
                  .setFunctionName('applyUpdateCcRecipientsAction')));
      cardSection.addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
              .setText('Update Bcc recipients')
              .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
                  .setFunctionName('applyUpdateBccRecipientsAction')));
      return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the subject field of the current email when the user clicks
     * on "Update subject" in the compose UI.
     *
     * Note: This is not the compose action that builds a compose UI, but
     * rather an action taken when the user interacts with the compose UI.
     *
     * @return {UpdateDraftActionResponse}
     */
    function applyUpdateSubjectAction() {
      // Get the new subject field of the email.
      // This function is not shown in this example.
      var subject = ['this is a subject'];
      var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
          .setUpdateDraftSubjectAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftSubjectAction()
              .addUpdateSubject(subject))
          .build();
      return response;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the To recipients of the current email when the user clicks
     * on "Update To recipients" in the compose UI.
     *
     * Note: This is not the compose action that builds a compose UI, but
     * rather an action taken when the user interacts with the compose UI.
     *
     * @return {UpdateDraftActionResponse}
     */
    function applyUpdateToRecipientsAction() {
      // Get the new To recipients of the email.
      // This function is not shown in this example.
      var toRecipients = ['johhny.appleseed@gmail.com'];
      var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
          .setUpdateDraftToRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftToRecipientsAction()
              .addUpdateToRecipients(toRecipients))
          .build();
      return response;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the Cc recipients  of the current email when the user clicks
     * on "Update Cc recipients" in the compose UI.
     *
     * Note: This is not the compose action that builds a compose UI, but
     * rather an action taken when the user interacts with the compose UI.
     *
     * @return {UpdateDraftActionResponse}
     */
    function applyUpdateCcRecipientsAction() {
      // Get the new Cc recipients of the email.
      // This function is not shown in this example.
      var ccRecipients = ['big.blue@montana.com'];
      var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
          .setUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction()
          .addUpdateCcRecipients(ccRecipients))
          .build();
      return response;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the Bcc recipients  of the current email when the user clicks
     * on "Update Bcc recipients" in the compose UI.
     *
     * Note: This is not the compose action that builds a compose UI, but
     * rather an action taken when the user interacts with the compose UI.
     *
     * @return {UpdateDraftActionResponse}
     */
    function applyUpdateBccRecipientsAction() {
      // Get the new Bcc recipients of the email.
      // This function is not shown in this example.
      var bccRecipients = ['spacer@gmail.com'];
      var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
          .setUpdateDraftBccRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBccRecipientsAction()
              .addUpdateBccRecipients(bccRecipients))
          .build();
      return response;
    }
```

When that code is opened, it looks like this compose UI display.

[image: compose ui]

**However**

these links only work one at a time and close the screen. You have to perform all the actions in multiple moves. I would like it to be able to perform more then one action at a time.

For example, if I click "Update Subject", the action works and the compose UI screen closes, but I don't want to open the add-on a second time to add the CC email address.

[image: add a subject working]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run these functions of `applyUpdateSubjectAction()`, `applyUpdateToRecipientsAction()`, `applyUpdateCcRecipientsAction()` and `applyUpdateBccRecipientsAction()` by one click at the dialog.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `buildComposeCard()` as follows.

```
function buildComposeCard() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Update email');
  cardSection.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Update email').setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('applyUpdateEmail')));
  return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
}
```

And, please add the following function.

```
function applyUpdateEmail() {
  var subject = ['this is a subject'];
  var toRecipients = ['johhny.appleseed@gmail.com'];
  var ccRecipients = ['big.blue@montana.com'];
  var bccRecipients = ['spacer@gmail.com'];

  return CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
  .setUpdateDraftSubjectAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftSubjectAction().addUpdateSubject(subject))
  .setUpdateDraftToRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftToRecipientsAction().addUpdateToRecipients(toRecipients))
  .setUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction().addUpdateCcRecipients(ccRecipients))
  .setUpdateDraftBccRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBccRecipientsAction().addUpdateBccRecipients(bccRecipients))
  .build();
}
```

- In this modification, you can see "Update email" at the opened dialog. When you click it, `addUpdateSubject`, `addUpdateToRecipients`, `addUpdateCcRecipients` and `addUpdateBccRecipients` are run.

#### Note:

- When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to the add-on. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Class UpdateDraftActionResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-action-response)
- [Class UpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-action-response-builder)